# Make Next ID using SEQUENCE SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

So this is the view

```
CREATE VIEW [worksheet01].[vw.product]
AS
    SELECT *
    FROM [worksheet01].[tbl_products]
GO
```

So here is my sequence

```
CREATE SEQUENCE [worksheet01].[seq_productId]
START WITH 10
INCREMENT BY 1
CACHE 20;
```

This is my `Insert` statement

```
INSERT INTO [worksheet01].[vw.product] (product_id, product_name, unit_price)
VALUES (([worksheet01].[seq_productId].NEXTVAL), 'Samsung Tab 10', '500')
```

I'm getting an error

> The multi-part identifier "worksheet01.seq_productId.NEXTVAL" could not be bound

Can someone explain what I am doing wrong please?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are really close.  Just change your insert to this:

```
INSERT INTO [worksheet01].[vw.product]
    (product_id,product_name, unit_price)
VALUES (NEXT VALUE FOR [worksheet01].seq_productID,'Samsung Tab 10', '500')
```